# How can I get the neighbor of an html element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, styles

Sample html:

```
<div class="container" id="neighbor-color-div">
        <button id="change-neighbour-color" onclick="change_neighbor_color()">Change my 
        neighbour color!</button>
        <button id="neighbour">Click the other button!</button>
</div>
<script src="./main.js" defer></script>
```

Sample main.js:

```
function change_neighbor_color() {
 ...
}
```

I don't know how to do that, but after I click the "change-neighbor-color" id button the text color of the other button should change to blue.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function change_neighbor_color() {
 document.getElementById('neighbour').style.color= 'blue';
}
```

Comment: Why you change it to red?

Comment: And it is asked for the text color and not the background color

Comment: I fixed the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Generic way**

You can pass at the **function call** a reference to the button which calls the function with `this`

```
 <button id="change-neighbour-color" onclick="change_neighbor_color(this)">
```

Then you have a reference to the called button element
`e.target;`

- Then get all your buttons with `querySelectorAll()`
- loop through all the buttons and check at which index the btn which called the function is by comparing it's **ID**.
- The best would be when your buttons you would like to involve have the same class names.

Then your neighbour will be the button at index +1

```js
        function change_neighbor_color(e) {
           let index;
           let nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
           nodes.forEach((n, ind) => {
           if(n.id === e.id){
           index = ind;
           }
           })
           
           if(index !== undefined && index !== null){
              nodes[index+1].style.color = "blue";
            }else{
           console.log("NO NEIGHBOUR FOUND");
            }

 
            }
```

```html
     <div class="container" id="neighbor-color-div">
                    <button id="change-neighbour-color" class="btn" onclick="change_neighbor_color(this)">Change my 
                    neighbour color!</button>
                    <button id="neighbour" class="btn">Click the other button!</button>
            </div>
            <script src="./main.js" defer></script>
```

**Non Generic Way**
Access the `neighbour` element by it's `id` and give it the **color** blue with `.style.color`

```
document.getElementById("neighbour").style.color = "blue";
```

```js
    
    function change_neighbor_color() {
document.getElementById("neighbour").style.color = "blue";
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="neighbor-color-div">
        <button id="change-neighbour-color" onclick="change_neighbor_color()">Change my 
        neighbour color!</button>
        <button id="neighbour">Click the other button!</button>
</div>
<script src="./main.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: While this works, I am quite certain the desire was for a more generic approach. *How can I get the neighbor of an html element in javascript?*

Comment: Nice name @JavaScript
For a more generic way you can use class names and querySelectorAll and then the desired elements neighbours are at index `[elementIndex -1] [elementIndex +1]`

Comment: Be aware of the second suggestion using `setAttribute()` which is going to drop all existing inline styles. If one also needs the styles in the markup, a combination of both would be more stable.

Comment: How would you combine them?

Comment: You first assign the property and after set the attribute using [`style.cssText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText). Alternatively, you can just add a class, which is the common practice nowadays.

Comment: but isn't the first solution a proper way to do it in a oneliner?

Comment: I've added a generic solution. There I pass a reference to the called button.